# Fallo con el .war en una aplicación java web

Tags: java, tomcat

Buenos días, estoy haciendo una aplicación java web con tomcat y eclipse. Al ejecutar el programa en eclipse con tomcat todo va bien y funciona correctamente pero cuando genero el fichero .war y lo coloco en la carpeta webapps de tomcat e inicio el servidor, poniendo la ruta correspondiente a mi proyecto en el navegador (en este caso localhost:8080/Proyecto/) me sale un error diciendo que el recurso no está disponible. No sé si tengo que cambiar la referencia en algún fichero o algo, la verdad es que estoy un poco perdida. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Asumo que el nombre generado para tu war es `Proyecto.war`. De ser así, entonces asegúrate que la aplicación haya iniciado en tomcat sin errores. Para ello, deberías ver los archivos de log del tomcat al respecto y ver si es que hay algún stacktrace que revisar. Si lo encuentras, por favor edita la pregunta y bríndanos el stacktrace para su revisión y análisis.

Answer (score 1):

Yo seguiria los siguientes pasos para encotnrar el error:

- 1º Generar el fichero WAR.
- 2º Al desplegarlo en el servidor, comprueba mediante la consola del tomcat que el recurso se ha desplegado de forma correcta. Al terminar el despliegue te indica si ha sido favorable o erroneo.
- 3º A) Si no se ha desplegado intentalo de nuevo, si aun asi no consigues desplegar es posible que el war se esta generando de manera erronea. (Comprueba también que no tengas problemas de memoria en el servidor que estas desplegando)
- 3º B) Si el war se ha desplegado correctamente, posiblemente estes accediendo a una ruta que no es la de tu proyecto, mira en el fichero de configuracion de tu proyecto cual es la ruta de acceso.

Puedes intentar algo de esto y nos cuentas, en base a lo que nos digas hago edit.